# How do write() and read() interact in C (<unistd.h>)?

Tags: c, io, ansi-escape

I am having trouble understanding how `read()` and `write()` work in C. The code that I am working with seems to be writing to `STDOUT_FILENO` and reading in the same data from `STDIN_FILENO`. I am wondering if that's supposed to be the case or not, since the two file descriptors are different.

I've already looked at the man pages and they didn't seem to help at all.

Here's the code:

```c
if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[6n", 4) != 4) return -1;
printf("\r\n");
char c;
while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) == 1) {
  if (iscntrl(c)) {
    printf("%d\r\n", c);
  } else {
    printf("%d ('%c')\r\n", c, c);
  }
}
```

The code outputs the escape sequence that were written out in the way the `if` statment formats it, which meant that the `STDIN_FILENO` somehow read the output of the `STDOUT_FILENO`. Is that how it's supposed to work, and if so, why?

Comment: If they're the ends of a pipe, sure, but that snippet isn't enough to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does exactly what you ask for:

`^[[6n` is the ansi escape sequence for DSR (device status report). This reports the current position of your cursor to your terminal input (stdin) in the format ^[[r;cR with "r" and "c" being "row" and "column". You can use this to determine the cursor location in your terminal.

This is a special feature of the *terminal*, which understands and processes such control codes, and is not the usual behaviour of stdin/stdout. Usually, you do *not* read from stdin what you wrote to stdout (it is also not the case here, it only looks similar!)

Comment: Quick question, so "\x1b[2J" clears the screen. Does that also write anything to stdin, or is it just different for each ansi escape sequence?

Comment: @Vasting It's different for each escape command. Only the ones that ask for information about the terminal would write responses to stdin.